# Printing characters for individual file lines in Java

Tags: java

I'm trying to print the 4th and 5th character from each line in a file.

This was a question on an online test. It was the one I couldn't figure out in time. I am just doing this for learning purposes.

Anyways, I'm trying to iterate through the lines and print those characters. Obviously I'm doing something wrong!

The file contains:

```
1001XXXXYYYYZZZZ
2002AAAABBBBCCCC
3003LLLLMMMMNNNN
4004SSSSTTTTUUUU
```

output should be:

```
1X
2A
3L
4S
```

Here is my code

```
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
public class Quiz9 {
    public static void main (String [] args) throws FileNotFoundException{
        Scanner in = new Scanner("/Users/abc/input.txt");
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter("/Users/abc/output.txt");
        String a;
        while (in.hasNextLine()) {
            for(int i=0;i<4;i++) {
                a = in.next();
                char b = a.charAt(5);
                char c = a.charAt(6);
                out.println(b +""+ c +"hello");
            }
        }
        in.close();
        out.close();
    }
}
```

I've had gotten it to produce some output, but it only says "\s" which isn't even on the list! I don't see where I am going wrong.

Comment: I think that the `for` loop within `while` is not needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [Scanner(File source)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#Scanner(java.io.File)) not the file name. 
You are getting `\s` because the 5th and 6th character of your file name is `s` and `\`.

try this...

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Quiz9 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(new File("/Users/abc/input.txt"));
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter("/Users/abc/output.txt");
        String a;
        while (in.hasNextLine()) {
            a = in.nextLine();
            char b = a.charAt(3);
            char c = a.charAt(4);
            out.write(b + "" + c + "\n");
        }
        in.close();
        out.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: So I should always use ```. . . new Scanner(new File("/file.txt"))``` for the Scanner file?

Comment: @KylianMurphy, when you need to scan from a file. glad it helped.

Answer (score 3):

You are scanning the filename, not the file content. Use e.g. Scanner(new File(...)) instead.

Comment: Oh, dammit! Thank you!